# Why is the VisualElement ID in Xamarin.Forms displayed as a string but actually is a GUID?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When i was playing around with EventHandlers in Xamarin.Forms i stumbled upon the fact, that the `x:Name` that was set for a specific element in the XAML file is actually displayed in the elements `ID` field when I'm sitting in the debugger (see screenshot).

[image]

However, as soon as I'm trying to get that `ID` field in code or when i observe the variable it turns out this field is a GUID. (see screenshot)

[image]

I'm wondering why that is and especially if it's possible to retrieve that value that i see in the debugger when i hover over with my mouse. It would be really handy because it would make it easier to work with these elements.

Edit: As requested here is some code from the xaml and also the event handler.

```
 <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource TextPrimaryColor}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" x:Name="LabelTarget" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" WidthRequest="50" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference StepperTarget}, Path=Value, StringFormat='{0:F1}' }" />
```

Event handler:

```
 private void OnLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
 { }
```

Comment: Hi , you can share the `Xaml` code in question , and this can be helpful to check that .

Comment: probably the issue with Visual studio debugger

Comment: @Morse Possible, but still - i would like to access the red marked string but i simply can't. If i access `sender.Id` then it's that Guid but the debugger gets the right string value that i want?

Comment: You should report the issue on Visual Studio developer community

Comment: @Morse i will, but still i would like to know if i can get to this string value somehow. If the debugger can display it, their should be a way to use it in code too, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here maybe a misunderstand of `Id`.

The `Id` of **Locals** output is the same as `visualLabel.Id` actually , just not show the same .

In **Locals** output , the `Id` should be for easy viewing, so the `x:Name` in **Xaml** is displayed directly .

**However** , in code we got is a **[Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.id?view=xamarin-forms)** style (*9b2dda4e-8d28-4080-a06e-4d16bdd82270*) , that's what should actually be displayed .

[image]

**Generally** , we will not use `Id` , because it shows a memory address .

**Solution** :

We can use `StyleId` to get the `x:Name` of **Xaml** .

Such as :

```
private void OnLabelTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     var obj = sender as Label;
     Console.WriteLine("------" + obj.Id);
     Console.WriteLine("------" + obj.StyleId);   
}
```

Here will output :

```
------9b2dda4e-8d28-4080-a06e-4d16bdd82270
------LabelTarget
```

Comment: Finally somehow who points that out. The values the debugger displays are still a bit weird though, but at least i know i can work with the `StyleId` now